# Jquery change background color

Tags: jquery

I was  trying out jquery with this example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").mouseover(function(){
        $("p#44.test").css("background-color","yellow");
        $("p#44.test").hide(1500);
        $("p#44.test").show(1500);
        $("p#44.test").css("background-color","red");
      });
    });
```

I expected the following to happen:

```
1. Color of <p> to turn yellow
2. <p> to slowly fade
3. <p> to slowly show
4. Color of <p> to turn red
```

But this is what actually happened:

```
1. <p> turned red
2. <p> slowly hid away
3. <p> slowly showed
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

The `.css()` function doesn't queue behind running animations, it's instantaneous.

To match the behaviour that you're after, you'd need to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").mouseover(function() {
    var p = $("p#44.test").css("background-color", "yellow");
    p.hide(1500).show(1500);
    p.queue(function() {
      p.css("background-color", "red");
    });
  });
});
```

The `.queue()` function waits for running animations to run out and then fires whatever's in the supplied function.

Answer (score 23):

try putting a delay on the last color fade.

```
$("p#44.test").delay(3000).css("background-color","red");
```

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html)
***ID's cannot start with digits!!!***

Comment: The second example won't work, since the `.css()` function doesn't chain into the animation flow.

Answer (score 19):

This is how it should be:

**Code:**

```
$(function(){
  $("button").mouseover(function(){
    var $p = $("#P44");
    $p.stop()
      .css("background-color","yellow")
      .hide(1500, function() {
          $p.css("background-color","red")
            .show(1500);
      });
  });
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/p7w9W/2/

**Explanation:**

You have to wait for the callback on the animating functions before you switch background color. You should also not use only numeric ID:s, and if you have an ID of your `<p>` there you shouldn't include a class in your selector.

I also enhanced your code (caching of the jQuery object, chaining, etc.)

**Update:**
As suggested by *VKolev* the color is now changing when the item is hidden.

Comment: Setting the $p.css("background-color", "red"); before the $p.show will make it a little bit nicer, without that blink effect after showing the p-content again.