# changing background color and alert it using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am starting to learn jquery and I tried to change the background colour and alert it with callback and it doesn't work probably something in my syntax is missing...

```
$("#b").click(function(){
  $("body").css("background-color,yellow",function(){
     alert("background-color has changed successfully");
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery change background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283141/jquery-change-background-color)

Comment: You forgot the `"` after _background-color_. This question should be closed.

Comment: This question is based on a syntax error by a new programmer and is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $("#b").click(function(e){
  $("body").css("background-color","yellow");
  alert("background-color has changed successfully");
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

You have missed **"** inside css's 'background-color' property.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/L2PpG/

Comment: You should at least explain what you changed to help the OP understand his error. Otherwise this answer is pretty worthless.

Answer (score 2):

I dont exactly know whether the function you used second time would work or not but try using this

```
 $("body").css('background-color','yellow');
alert("COLOR CHANGED");
```

Comment: thank you for the help but I already tried you'r asnwer, my question is: if there is a way to do it with callback like first i changes the background color and the alert on it.

Comment: ah sorry. So what exactly do u want? First the background color to be changed and then the alert to appear? is that it?

Answer (score 1):

and if u want to alert the color of the element, in this case yellow then use this code rather than my previous one:-

```
 $("#b").click(function(){
         $("body").css('background-color','yellow');
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");

    alert("Color Changed to "+ color);
    });
```

Comment: :) Kindly accept the code as correct if it worked..  :P