# Keyboard keycode from arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get a response for when visitor uses the keys right and left

```
<script>
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    key = String.fromCharCode(event.which)
    if(key == '37' || key == '39') {
      $('main').html('You pressed : ' + key)
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  });
</script>
```

It's not working. what did work was the line

```
if(key == 'a')
```

I used this table to find the code https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Is it because jQuery has different table? or maybe I should load JavaScript as well? then how do I do use the two of them? (jQuery and JavaScript?)?

EDIT:

I think I got it

```
String.fromCharCode(event.which)
```

JavaScript can't read strings as numbers? do I need to use different function? I'm new to this can you tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I find for myself that when I go to implement these sorts of "get item from event", that a simple `console.log(event)` does wonders.  I'd start with:

```
$('body').on('keypress', function(evt){
    console.log('Event: ', evt);
});
```

Then, press the right and left arrow keys and see what happens.

First, an observation: I note that you're comparing the string `'37'`, which is distinct from the integer value `37`.  The former is two or four bytes (depending on how the JS implementation stores characters), while the latter is one byte.  Is that your intention after reading the appropriate APIs?

Second, as a specific suggestion, if you're using jQuery, take advantage of it's normalization routines.  In this case, `event.which` is returning 0, but you can use `event.keyCode` which is probably what you want to compare:

```
if ( 37 === event.keyCode ) {
  // ...
}
else if ( 39 === event.keyCode ) {
  // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i tried to upvote but it does'nt let me. can you help me with using jquery with changing background? i tried this

if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) 
{
$('main').css('background ','yellow')
event.preventDefault()
}
})

but it does'nt work

Comment: Unfortunately, without more context, no.  Suggest you read the jQuery API, and/or post a new question.  This question has been answered.

Comment: I think you're supposed to submit another question for follow-ups like this, but to help you out, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283141/jquery-change-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the `keydown` event. Also, no reason to use the `String.fromCharCode`, you can just compare the integers. Something like this would work

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 37 || event.which == 39) {
    var key = event.which == 37 ? 'left' : 'right';
    $('main').html('You pressed : ' + key)
    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```