# Changing styles for certain div based on their id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vuejs2

I want to change the background color of `<div>`s of `id`s `childDiv1` and `childDiv4` only..how to do such kind of thing (**note** that the list of `div` may be a huge list and the the wanted `div` list is from an array)
Eg:-> 
`stylingdivs:{'childDiv1','childDiv4'}`
please help me with this

```
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv1342">
    First Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv2244">
    Second Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv3342">
    Third Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv4324">
    Fourth Div Child
  </div>
  `<div class="childDiv5324">
    Fifth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div class="childDiv6324">
    Sixth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div class="childDiv7323">
    Seventh Div Child
  </div>`
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283141/jquery-change-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

Read over [`CSS .class Selector`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) which will help you understand how `selectors` work in `CSS`.

Also, read over [`jQuery Multiple Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

---

```js
$('.childDiv1, .childDiv4').css('background-color', 'cyan');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv1">
    First Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv2">
    Second Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv3">
    Third Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv4">
    Fourth Div Child
  </div>
  `<div class="childDiv5">
    Fifth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div class="childDiv6">
    Sixth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div class="childDiv7">
    Seventh Div Child
  </div>`
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Herre is a link to W3Schools [CSS selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)..

In your css simply put:

```
.parentDiv > .childDiv1, .childDiv4 {
background-color: #666666;
}
```

or just reference the child divs

```
.childDiv1, .childDiv4 {
background-color: #666666;
}
```

btw: you are using classes in your example, not ids..

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to have them statically, CSS is enough:

```
.childDiv1, .childDiv4 {
  background-color: your-color;
}
```

If they need to be changed dynamically, simple Javascript should work for this.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".childDiv1, .childDiv4").forEach(
  div => div.style.backgroundColor = "your-color");
```

Answer (score 0):

You say id so I change your html to be id

```
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div id="childDiv1">
    First Div Child
  </div>
  <div id="childDiv2">
    Second Div Child
  </div>
  <div id="childDiv3">
    Third Div Child
  </div>
  <div id="childDiv4">
    Fourth Div Child
  </div>
  `<div id="childDiv5">
    Fifth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div id="childDiv6">
    Sixth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div id="childDiv7">
    Seventh Div Child
  </div>`
</div>

<script>
 document.selectAll("#childDiv1, #childDiv4").style.backgroundColor = "red";

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery to give background color in `'childDiv1','childDiv4'` with this situation no problem if the list of div may be a huge.

I think you want like this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
               var parentDiv = $('.parentDiv').find('div')
               $(parentDiv).eq(0).css('background','green');
               $(parentDiv).eq(3).css('background','green');
           })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv1">
    First Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv2">
    Second Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv3">
    Third Div Child
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv4">
    Fourth Div Child
  </div>
  `<div class="childDiv5">
    Fifth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div class="childDiv6">
    Sixth Div Child
  </div>`
  `<div class="childDiv7">
    Seventh Div Child
  </div>`
</div>
```

Comment: what if the `div` id is a random number(child div's) and those random IDs are saved in an array

Comment: but you are selecting the child `div`s directly which are under the `parentDiv` as `0` and `3`.is there a better way to catch them.

Comment: If id is a random then you can select with class instead of id or you can use `this()`